# Ruby on Rails 3 - How to create 2 different forms for sign up based on Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

In my application I have two different members - User and Company. I have implemented authentication based on Devise. Now, when I visit "/members/sign_up" I have one common form for both of them.

I'd like to have 2 different links for sign up, for example - "members/user/sign_up" and "members/company/sign_up" with member's specific forms.

How it could be achieved ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *might* do what you're looking for — update your routes as follows:

```
scope "members" do
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :companies
end
```

This assumes you have two devise models.